# How to queue a build in Dev Ops with Dev Ops Rest Api

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

How do i queue a build with the Dev Ops Rest Api.

What i have tried so far:

Working:

```
`https://${config.azureEndpoints.instance}/${config.azureEndpoints.collection}/${config.azureEndpoints.project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1
body: 

              definition: {
                id: 448
              },
               queue: {
                 id: buildId,
                 name: 'Hosted VS2017',
                 pool: {
                   id: 4,
                   name: 'Hosted VS2017',
                   isHosted: true
                 }
               },
              parameters: `{"parameters":"${parameters}"}`,
```

not Working:

```
Body:
id: 546
name: "Azure Pipelines"
pool: {id: 25, name: "Azure Pipelines", isHosted: true}
id: 25
isHosted: true
name: "Azure Pipelines"

Error: 
Provisioning request delayed or failed to send 3 time(s). This is over the 
limit of 3 time(s). 

[Warning 1]
There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response 
code from remote provider InternalServerError
```

These are the values coming from:

https://${config.azureEndpoints.instance}/${config.azureEndpoints.collection}/${config.azureEndpoints.project}/_apis/build/definitions?${definitionId}&api-version=5.1

I captured the the request coming from the dev ops gui when triggering it manually. It does the same but adds:

```
agentSpecification: {identifier: "ubuntu-16.04"}
```

But this value is not in the Definition and there is no endpoint to get possible agentSpecifications.

TLDR: How to Queue a build in Dev Ops using the existing definition in Dev Ops?

Comment: How are you invoking the request? How are you building and providing the authentication?

Comment: I'am using axios and i am doing a standard post request. By now i am not handling any authentication. I just login into dev ops and doing the reuqest in the same Browser.

Answer (score 0):

> How to queue a build in Dev Ops with Dev Ops Rest Api?

Just to specified the build **definitionId** in the request body will enable queue this build through API.

Here is sample script which work fine on my side, you can try with that:

```
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }
$body = '
{ 
        "definition": {
            "id": {build definition id}
        } 
}

$Uri = "https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1-preview.2"
$buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body $bodyString -Headers $headers
```

You can see that if this build queued by the API successfully, you will see the details about queue time and the queued user.

[image]

Comment: Calling: https://${config.azureEndpoints.instance}/${config.azureEndpoints.collection}/${config.azureEndpoints.project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1-preview.2 with {"definition":{"id":136},"parameters":"..."} results in the same Error like before. The build is triggered but returns an Error before actually doing sth: There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider InternalServerError

Comment: I now switched the Agent Pool in the build definition from a hosted Pool to a private Pool. Now the build is triggered correctly. But i dont get, why you cant trigger a build with a hosted Agent except when you provide the exact Information about Pool and Agent. Which should be in the definition but are not.

Comment: In the request body, you are specifying the agent which in the Hosted pool? If this, you could not, this is a as designed rule. For hosted agent, you can only specify the type, for agent, it will be assigned to user randomly.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use [VSTeam](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/VSTeam/6.3.2) to queue the build for you or [review the code of VSTeam](https://github.com/DarqueWarrior/vsteam) to see how it is done. The official docs for the API are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).